# How to identify what is causing unusually high CPU load in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a MySQL 5.7 server that is recently under very high CPU load, but no clue where this load comes from.

Looking at the MySQL process list, it does not look like the server is doing much. There are some connections, but nothing heavy or special that could explain the high CPU.

In efforts to improve the situation I have been doing some data cleanup and applying some advice given by the `mysqltuner` script, but nothing seems to help much.

My last thought is that maybe something is damaged (some tables?) and MySQL is busy in the background, but I don't know if this makes any sense.

So my question is really, how to go about this?

Looking at the process list, like everyone is saying, is not giving me the answers I need. Something inside MySQL is definitely eating CPU behind the scenes.

This server is quite powerful and there is plenty of RAM and CPU cores, so this is certainly not a hardware limitation.

Comment: Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report
information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Answer (score 1):

The slowlog.  Granted, this picks up on both high CPU and high I/O, but still it will give you what you are looking for.

Suggestions on digesting, etc: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Often the 'cure' is an appropriate composite index.